# C# get window handle after starting a process

Tags: c#, window-handles

Is there a way to get the window handle (IntPtr) for a window after its launched from a C# app with Process.Start()?

Comment: Process p = Process.Start("Notepad");
            p.WaitForInputIdle();
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, CBox.Handle);

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If it's the main window you're after, [`Process.MainWindowHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx) will give you what you need.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
process.MainWindowHandle;
```

It probably is 0 when launching the app, so you might want to loop and sleep until it is filled up.

Comment: Hi Jan,
For me, the handle is always zero and never goes to any other value, even after infinite looping. I use the following code:

proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Documents and Settings\SUM\Desktop\PortableApps\Notepad++Portable\Notepad++Portable.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Empty;
                proc.Start();


                IntPtr appHwnd = proc.MainWindowHandle;

                while (appHwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    appHwnd = proc.MainWindowHandle;
                }

What's wrong?

Comment: According to this (http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showpost.php?s=b115a21c0601804f80c9a2680db9c38f&p=461829&postcount=4) it may also be zero because an application does show a dialog or initializing flash first.

Answer (score 6):

This is not a recent topic but the answers are incomplete.

I agree with the Process.MainWindowHandle solution and to wait for the value but not with Sleep.

> If you have just started a process and want to use its main window handle, consider using the WaitForInputIdle method to allow the process to finish starting, ensuring that the main window handle has been created.

[Process.WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This overload applies only to processes with a user interface and, therefore, a message loop.

Comment: I think this should actually be a comment.

Comment: i am sorry, for some reasons, this wait.... function throw the exception(there is only one), i will resolve with Sleep and Refresh

Comment: The `Process.WaitForInputIdle` seems to return almost immediately if it's used on a WPF application. I believe this is due to the WPF internals...

Comment: It returns almost immediately for my .NET 4.5 application.  Previous person said WPF, mine is just desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

You could also call Refresh() on the process to be sure the info in accurate