# Set an external EXE as TopMost

Tags: c#, process

How would you set a program to become the topmost application using Process.Start or something along those lines

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to make it TopMost application or you need to set focus temporarily to another application?

Comment: Nothing close to "Process.Start or something along those lines".  An EXE is never top-most, a window is.  It requires pinvoke, SetWindowPos() with HWND_TOPMOST.  Finding the correct window handle is the typical problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After starting the proccess, 
I would start by getting the [window handle of that process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421166/c-sharp-get-window-handle-after-starting-a-process)

Then, I would use [SetWindowPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SetWindowPos) to set it to be the [topmost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528473/c-sharp-make-a-window-topmost-using-a-window-handle)

Notice that this requires using PInvoke. The 3 links should point you in the right direction.