# How to run Chrome with --app as always on top from C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, topmost

I need to run Chrome with  --app and keep it always on top.
I have tried everything I know of.

```
Process process = Process.Start("chrome.exe", " --app=" + "http://10.0.0.10:88/MyServer?/1/playlist/Request_1.m3u8");
```

This runs Chrome to play the hls file, but the desired outcome is that it run in the window opened, not in the top-most window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set an external EXE as TopMost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112081/set-an-external-exe-as-topmost)

Comment: Since you're using C#, you may consider using WebView2 control (which is based on chrome): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

Comment: WebView2 is perfect solution for me, thanks , i did not know it exist