# Find window from process

Tags: c#, process, window

I have a process with `GetProcessesByName("" + Path,"X.X.X.X")` and I need to know the handle of the window which is launched from it.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421166/c-sharp-get-window-handle-after-starting-a-process

Answer (score 1):

There's [`MainWindowHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) property which can help you for that  :

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("yourprocess.exe");

foreach (Process p in processes)
{
    IntPtr windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle;
}
```